# how can I select a default option in a dropdown list?

Tags: javascript, php, cakephp

I have this JS file, by default i want to make an option selected . I mean, i want to make selected the Country "`USA`" with the value "`USA`" .
This is what i have by default :

[image]

This is the JS file :

```
var town_country_arr = new Array("Canada", "USA");    
    var s_a = new Array();        
    s_a[0]="";        
    s_a[1]="Alberta|British Columbia|Manitoba|New Brunswick|Newfoundland|Northwest Territories|Nova Scotia|Nunavut|Ontario|Prince Edward Island|Quebec|Saskatchewan|Yukon Territory";

    s_a[2]="Alabama|Alaska|Arizona|Arkansas|California|Colorado|Connecticut|Delaware|District of Columbia|Florida|Georgia|Hawaii|Idaho|Illinois|Indiana|Iowa|Kansas|Kentucky|Louisiana|Maine|Maryland|Massachusetts|Michigan|Minnesota|Mississippi|Missouri|Montana|Nebraska|Nevada|New Hampshire|New Jersey|New Mexico|New York|North Carolina|North Dakota|Ohio|Oklahoma|Oregon|Pennsylvania|Rhode Island|South Carolina|South Dakota|Tennessee|Texas|Utah|Vermont|Virginia|Washington|West Virginia|Wisconsin|Wyoming";

    function print_town_country(town_country_id){        
        // given the id of the <select> tag as function argument, it inserts <option> tags        
        var option_str = document.getElementById(town_country_id);        
        option_str.length=0;        
        option_str.options[0] = new Option('Pays','');        
        option_str.selectedIndex = 0;        
        for (var i=0; i<town_country_arr.length; i++) {        
            option_str.options[option_str.length] = new Option(town_country_arr[i],town_country_arr[i]);

        }

    }
```

EDIT : My view in Cake

```
<div class="form-group">
                          <div class="col-xs-6">
                            <?php echo $this->Form->input('country', array('type' => 'select', 'class' => 'form-control', 'label' => 'Pays', 'id' => 'town_country', 'onchange' => "print_state('state',this.selectedIndex);", 'selected' => $selectedcountry, 'empty' => 'Pays')); ?>
                          </div>
                      </div>

                      <div class="form-group">
                          <div class="col-xs-6">
                      <?php 
                      echo $this->Form->input('localisation', array('type' => 'select', 'class' => 'form-control', 'label' => 'Localisation', 'id' => 'state', 'empty' => $namelocalisation,
                            'options' => $localisations)); ?>
                          </div>
                      </div>  

                      <script language="javascript">print_town_country("town_country");</script>
```

the variable selectedcountry equal USA ...

With Firebug :

```
<div class="col-xs-6">
<div class="input select required">
<label for="town_country">Pays</label>
<select id="town_country" class="form-control" onchange="print_state('state',this.selectedIndex);" name="data[Town][country]">
<option value="">Pays</option>
<option value="Canada">Canada</option>
<option value="USA">USA</option>
</select>
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: show us your html also

Comment: `option_str.value = "USA";` or better, see below vv

Comment: It's in the documentation: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLOptionElement.Option

Comment: Please anyone: Vote for Close duplicate 1545764.

Comment: Simply use the controller to set a default value. Thats the cleanest approach.

Answer (score 1):

You might not need `Javascript`. You could simply put.

```
<select>

<option value="Pays">Pays</option>
<option value="Canada">Canada</option>
<option value="USA" selected>USA</option> //This will be the default selected value
<option></option>

</select>
```

In other-words, you simple add a `select` *attribute* on the option you want to be selected by default

For native javascript use the setAttribute like this:

```
.setAttribute("selected","selected")
```

If you like `jQuery`, you could do:

```
$('select option:eq(2)').prop('selected', true);
```

Answer (score 0):

Some misuse the `selected`-Attribute as default selection. Unfortunatelly there is no such thing like a `default`-Attribute but: the **first Element** is selected by standard-convention.

Set the option you like to have as the default-value at first option in the `<select>`.

Comment: i did it in my view with Cake, but it's still select "Pays", the empty value .

Comment: Either the browser set it for you or JavaScript or HTML select `Pays` for you.

Comment: Ok if i don't have "Pays" i don't care, i want to select "USA" by default , not if it'st he first element, also if it's the second .

Comment: Then you mean you like to make a selection for the User, this is **not** a default value. A default value is a suggestion, a selection is a purpose. By select a value you make a purpose!

Comment: That's why in Cake, i added "'selected' => $selectedcountry", but the JS file select always "Pays", if i remove Pays in my JS file the browser will select Canada, i just want to set selected for USA, so the last element . (with value USA)

Comment: Can you please add the HTML of the `<select>` that has been generated to the Question?

Comment: I edited my post . This is what i generated when the page is loaded , you could see that we can't find the selected attribute .